# Removing NewsFeed comments with Remove-SPSocialItemByDate throws SQLException

Tags: 2013, powershell, user-profile-service

I am trying to remove all Mysite newsfeed comments via powershell in preparation for a new site release (getting debugging and test comments out, etc.)...

I am using the Remove-SPSocialItemByDate powershell command ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607934(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607934%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) and following multiple examples found there and in the Powershell for sharepoint 2013 How-To... but I consistently get the same error.

code:

```
Add-PsSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
##This script removes comments, ratings and tags made before EndDate value
$userProfProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where { $_.DisplayName -eq 'User Profile Service Application' }
$userProfProxy
Remove-SPSocialItemByDate -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $userProfProxy -RemoveComments 1 -EndDate 7/1/2014
```

Error:

> Name                 Type                 Id
>   ----                 ----                 --
>   User Profile Serv... User Profile Serv... 08d859ab-14e6-45a0-80cb-e2c74c312422
>
> Remove-SPSocialItemByDate : Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.
>   At line:7 char:1
>   + Remove-SPSocialItemByDate -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $userProfProxy -Remove ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...moveSocialItems:SPCmdletRemoveSocialItems) [Remove-SPSocialItemByDate], SqlException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveSocialItems

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Add-PsSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$userProfProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where { $_.DisplayName -eq 'User Profile Service Application' }
Remove-SPSocialItemByDate -RemoveComments 1 -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $userProfProxy -EndDate 7/1/2014
```

## To remove tag

```
Remove-SPSocialItemByDate -RemoveTags 1 -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy c6681d53-e6c4-432f-9f31-22d3de81b00c -EndDate 9/15/2009
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing correctly, but this looks just like the code that I posted that is not working.

Comment: the order is different. The code that i posted is state       -RemoveComment before -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy